# How to add String variable to SQL query - Java, SpringBoot

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot

I have an SQL query that looks like this:

```
public void getUser(String userId, String dbName) {

String q = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE \"TEST_DATABASE\".\"PUBLIC\".\"USER_TABLE_TEMP\" AS SELECT \"USERID\", \"FIRSTNAME\", \"LASTNAME\" from \"TEST_DATABASE\".\"PUBLIC\".\"USER\"";

jdbcTemplatePerBrand.values().forEach(tab -> tab.query(q, s -> {}));
}
```

I am trying to pass custom `dbName` to query and I have tried something like this:

```
 public void getUser(String userId, String dbName) {

String q = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE \"?\".\"PUBLIC\".\"USER_TABLE_TEMP\" AS SELECT \"USERID\", \"FIRSTNAME\", \"LASTNAME\" from \"?\".\"PUBLIC\".\"USER\"";

jdbcTemplatePerBrand.values().forEach(tab -> tab.query(q, s -> {}, dbName));

}
```

I am getting following error:

```
Database '"?"' does not exist or not authorized.
```

Comment: I'm not expert with JDBCTemplate, but database object names (schema, table, column) _cannot_ be bound with a `?` placeholder.  The `?` placeholder is only for query data.

Comment: I am not sure... so how would it be then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to add a variable as `+dbName+` to my query.

What was bordering me was the `" "` that I didn't know how to handle.

I am using Snowflake and my database name is written in `" "`.

So the solution was that I do this:

```
public void getUser(String userId, String dbName) {

 String q = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE \""+dbName+"\".\"PUBLIC\".\"USER_TABLE_TEMP\" AS SELECT \"USERID\", 
 \"FIRSTNAME\", \"LASTNAME\" from \"TEST_DATABASE\".\"PUBLIC\".\"USER\"";

 jdbcTemplatePerBrand.values().forEach(tab -> tab.query(q, s -> {}));

}
```

So what I have learned from this is that if you want to add variable to your query use `+variableName+` but always be aware of how your database name is written in the database you use.

Also, another **NOTE**

For example, I am writing queries for Snowflake in Java code.

And for variables that I want to place in statement like:

`CREATE TABLE +tableName+` I do use `+tableName+` approach

But when I want to add it in my `WHERE` statement, then I am using `?` sign.

```
String qu = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE \""+dbName+"\".\"PUBLIC\".\"USER_TABLE_TEMP\" AS SELECT \"ID\", \"FIRST_NAME\", \"LAST_NAME\" from \""+dbName+"\".\"PUBLIC\".\"USER_TABLE\"\n" +
                "                where \"ID\" = ?\n" +
                "                union all\n" +
                "                select \"ID\",\"ACCOUNT_NAME\", \"ACCOUNT_NUMBER\" from \""+dbName+"\".\"PUBLIC\".\"ACCOUNT_DATA\"\n" +
                "                where \"ID\" = ?";*/
```

So find out what works for your database and use it :)

This is Snowflake/Java example.

Answer (score 0):

try the following approach.

```
String q = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE "+ dbName +".\"PUBLIC\".\"USER_TABLE_TEMP\" AS SELECT \"USERID\", \"FIRSTNAME\", \"LASTNAME\" from \"?\".\"PUBLIC\".\"USER\"";
```

Comment: if your problem has been resolved, kindly share the solution.